# Rendering HTML in LWC via lightning-formatted-rich-text

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce-cms

We are trying to create a custom LWC component to render the HTML content using content managed REST api. We are getting the content, but when rendering in LWC the HTML is rendered with unformatted tags. We are using lightning-formatted-rich-text render the HTML.

Comment: Which tags are not correctly rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Only use this as a last resort if you desperately want to render all of the html coming from the external service.**

Use the HTML directive `lwc:dom="manual"` [more info here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_directives). Since you are getting a HTML string from an external service, `appendChild()` or modifying `innerHTML` appears to be a good fit in this use case.

LWC HTML template:

```
<template>
    <div lwc:dom="manual" class="my-content"></div>
</template>
```

LWC JS module:

```
handleGetHtmlContent(htmlContent) {
    const container = this.template.querySelector('.my-content');
    container.innerHTML = htmlContent;
}
```

Comment: Allowing any HTML to be rendered exposes the page to HTML/JavaScript injection attacks (XSS or CSRF). This could be why some of the elements are not getting rendered for the OP when using the existing lightning components.

Comment: True. Assumption was that OP was attempting to render tags that are unsupported by the rich text component. Would advise sanitising the html to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: There's probably a reason the tags are unsupported by the rich text component, where that reason is XSS or similar...

Comment: Right now the reason is that Salesforce have released a new accordian element to the knowledge article editor but this is not one of the tags supported by the lightning-formatted-rich-text component.